# Appending to an array vs writing to file

Tags: java, arrays, file, memory-management

I'm writing a program which takes in a byte array of potentially millions of bytes, reads each one from a ByteArrayInputStream, and if the byte is not "printable" (ascii 32-126), that byte is encoded in a certain way and written to a ByteArrayOutputStream instance; if the byte is "printable" it is directly written to that same ByteArrayOutputStream instance.
So from a broader view I am taking in a byte array, and getting back a similar byte array except certain characters have been encoded.

My question is: would it be faster to write my data out to a file or to continuously be writing to this OutputStream?

Comment: Why would you think that writing to disk is going to make things faster? Hard disks - even SSDs - are slow relative to memory access.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no right answer - question is under-specified

Comment: File I/O has serious overheads depending on your hardware set-up. Memory is virtually always going to be faster. Millions of bytes is only a few megabytes, so I don't know why you would want to write to a file since there's no real risk of running out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be faster to write the data to your output stream. Writing to a file will involve disk access, which is slower than access to the RAM where the byte array inside the ByteArrayOutputStream lives.

However, if you eventually want to write your byte array out to some other place (say a file) then the intermediate step of the ByteArrayOutputStream is unnecessary and you should just write straight to the end destination e.g. FileOutputStream.